# $R$ has only one maximal ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, ring-theory, ideals

Let $F$ be a field. Let $R$ be the set of all upper triangular matrices of the ring $M_{n}(F)$ with the property that its coefficients on the main diagonal are all the same. Prove that $R$ has only one maximal ideal.

Help me.

Comment: Since your ring is not commutative, you should specify whether maximal ideal is left, right or two-sided (and unique as such). It is in fact all of them at once, but it should be clear what is being asked to be proved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The maximal ideal $I$ consists of all matrices with $0$  on the main diagonal. Indeed, it is easy to check that $I$ is an ideal. On other hand, every matrix $M\not\in I$ is invertible, so $M$ cannot contain in any proper ($\ne R$) ideal.

Comment: May you explain more precise?

Comment: I will add the answer.

Comment: Why  "M cannot contain in any proper (≠R) ideal"?.

Comment: The inverse of $M$ is upper triangular again, so $M^{-1}\in R$. If $M$ is contained in an ideal $J$, then $E=MM^{-1}\in J$. Hence $J=R$.

Comment: I agree with you. But how to show the maximality of $I$?

Comment: It follows from the fact that $R\setminus I$ consists of invertible matrices.

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 6):

Hint: what are the non invertible elements in the ring? Do they form an ideal?

Comment: Can you explain more precisely? I need more details.

Comment: The maximal ideal of $R$? What is it?

Comment: An element generates the trivial ideal (the whole ring) iff it is invertible. If not, then it is included in a maximal ideal. So if a ring has only one maximal ideal, that must contain all noninvertible elements.